# cmake fails: Inconsistency detected by ld.so

Tags: catkin-make, ros-indigo, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently set up a new Ubuntu 14 VM to install indigo on. I installed indigo, and since I'm working with an Aldebaran Nao humanoid robot, I also downloaded the naoqi SDK. Then, I downloaded these packages: nao_robot, nao_extra, roboticsgroup_gazebo_plugins, pal_msgs, and pal_gazebo_plugins. I tried a catkin_make after this, and got the following error:

```
Base path: /home/amstrudy/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/amstrudy/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/amstrudy/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/amstrudy/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/amstrudy/catkin_ws/install
```

Running command:

```
cmake /home/amstrudy/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/amstrudy/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/amstrudy/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/amstrudy/catkin_ws/build"
    
    Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-version.c: 224: _dl_check_map_versions: Assertion `needed != ((void *)0)' failed!
    Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I uninstalled the packages, commented out the source lines and LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PYTHON_PATH lines in my bashrc (which pointed to stuff in naoqi), deleted and reinstalled indigo, but still no luck. I know that catkin_make worked as some point because I used it to setup my catkin_ws. I've researched around but haven't found a solution.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I tried deleting the naoqi SDK from my VM, and voila, cmake (and catkin_make) are both back up and running. I have no idea how this could be? I need naoqi, so any ideas as to how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270777/cmake-fails:-inconsistency-detected-by-ld.so/) by [amstrudy](https://answers.ros.org/users/31757/amstrudy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-09-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-12**:
I edited your question to make it easier to read. I did my best but I feel that I may have mangled it a bit. Feel free to redo it, but please don't use `code` tags. Just highlight the code/errors/commands and click the `101010` button.

**Comment by [amstrudy](https://answers.ros.org/users/31757/amstrudy/) on 2017-09-12**:
@jayess thank you!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-12**:
What does running `catkin_make` from the root of your workspace give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why are you directly invoking `cmake`? You should be using `catkin_make` from the root of your workspace.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amstrudy](https://answers.ros.org/users/31757/amstrudy/) on 2017-09-12**:
I'm not directly invoking cmake, but catkin_make. When I was investigating the error I narrowed the problem down to cmake. Any attempt to use the command results in the above error.

Also, please see my edits above!